# Spring MVC library doesnt show up in server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am using eclipse as my ide. I had imported some spring projects from my instructor. In those when I expand the project in server deployment list, it shows spring web library. I created some project of my own from scratch but in those i cant see any expanding icon on my project in the server deployment list. And my project isnt running as well. What can I do so that my project also shows up the library? I checked the deployment library and it shows all the libs.

Also in my marker I see this error. How to correct this.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'E:/path/to/local/repo/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar' in project 'SpringTemp' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file SpringTemp      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it .

Changed the version of spring framework version in POM file from 3.1.1 to 3.2.3 and it worked.